# Indy 10 socket error 11001 Host not found

Tags: c++builder, indy

I am trying to send email using Indy 10.5.7 on C++ Builder XE but I get Host not found error.  I added TIdSMTP, TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdMessage components.  I set the host to smtp.office365.com, the port to 587 and UseTLS to utUseExplicitTLS.  The username and password are set for the email address of the account I need to connect with.

I am trying to send the email using :

```
IdMessage1->From->Name = Name->Text;
IdMessage1->From->Address = EmailAddress->Text;
IdMessage1->Body = Msg->Lines;

try
{
    IdSMTP1->Connect(1000);
    try
    {
        IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1);
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdSMTP1->Disconnect();
    }
}
catch (const Exception &E)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, E.Message.c_str(), L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

Comment: I tried to upgrade but I can't compile due to my c++ builder edition being starter.  Can I use the pre-built versions on 'http://www.mjfreelancing.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13&Itemid=16' to upgrade Indy ?

Comment: I don't use a starter edition, what problems are you having with compiling? It does not appear that MJ's precompiled binaries are up-to-date, let alone support modern IDE editions in the past few years.

Comment: It says 'This version of the product does not support command line compiling'.

Comment: in that case, to update Indy, you will likely have to add Indy's source files directly to your project. Or, make your own C++Builder project files for Indy and compile it in the IDE. Indy stopped providing native C++Builder project files many years ago since the Delphi project files can be compiled on the command line for C++Builder. Indy does not account for the lack of command line compiling in the starter edition (in fact, I was not even aware of that restriction until just now).

Comment: I copied the source files into my project and compiled my project.  I still receive the same error, do you know what could cause this, everything else can connect to the internet.

Comment: oh, that issue. I didn't notice at first what your code was doing wrong. I have now added an answer to explain what is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```cpp
IdSMTP1->Connect(1000);
```

In Indy 9, `Connect()` had an overload that accepted a timeout as input. But in Indy 10, that overload was removed, and the timeout parameter was reimplemented as a `ConnectTimeout` property.

Your original code compiles because `Connect()` in Indy 10 has an overload that takes a hostname `String` as input, overwriting the `Host` property, and `(Ansi|Unicode)String` has a constructor that accepts an `int` as input. Thus, your code is effectively doing this

```cpp
IdSMTP1->Connect(String(1000));
```

Which tries to connect to a hostname named `"1000"`, ignoring the `"smtp.office365.com"` hostname you assigned to the `Host` property. That is why you are getting socket error 11001.

You need to replace the offending line with this code instead:

```cpp
//IdSMTP1->Connect(1000);
IdSMTP1->ConnectTimeout = 1000;
IdSMTP1->Connect();
```